# Reference for the reflexion of sound in connection with boundary conditions of the wave equation

Tags: acoustics, specific-reference

In 3D, the homogenous wave equation

$$ -\Delta_x u(x,t) + \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} (x,t) \ = \ 0 \ \ \mathrm{in} \ \Omega \times (0, \infty) $$

can approximately describe soundwaves in air, with $u(x,t)$ being the difference in pressure at point $x \in \Omega$ at time $t \in (0,\infty)$. 
Now depending on what boundary conditions you choose, you can simulate so called "acoustic weak" walls by Dirichlet b.c., i.e.

$$  u(x,t) \ = \ 0 \ \ \mathrm{on} \ \partial \Omega \times (0, \infty), $$

or simulate so called "acoustic hard" walls by Neumann b.c., i.e.

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial \overrightarrow{n}} (x,t) \ = \ 0 \ \ \mathrm{auf} \ \partial \Omega \times (0, \infty), $$
with $\overrightarrow{n}(x)$ the outer normal at $x \in \partial \Omega$.

Now, does anyone know a good reference for these "acoustic weak" or "acoustic hard" walls in connection with boundary conditions? As far i gathered together that these conditions have something to do with the sound reflexion of the walls. Sadly, my local maths library doesn't really support much of this topic $-$ most books about acoustics i've found basically looked like picture books and weren't really worthy to cite (the point is, that i deal with solving certain standing waves and need some interpretations of the these two types of boundary conditions for an application) 
I would be grateful for some suggestions!

Comment: With all due respect, an "acoustic hard" is a hard wall.  An "acoustic weak" wall is where the medium ends (doesn't apply for air, obviously).  Not sure what you need to know.